# System administration information missing in CME after Tridion installation

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

We are done with installation of SDL Tridion (migration from 5.3 to 2011SP1)
The tridion installation went smoothly.

However while accessing CMS from browser we are facing some issues.

1. Not able to access any Administration item (users, groups etc) . We got error in ribb"Invalid URI: cme:accmng" while accessing any tridion administration item. The publications are showing content properly.
2. We reinstalled tridion and now the issue remains with new JS error on page:

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;
>   Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR
>   3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E) Timestamp: Wed, 17 Oct 2012 14:35:40 UTC
>
> Message: Error: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
>   Line: 17 Char: 3650 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://[Serverurl]/WebUI/Editors/CME/Views/Dashboard/Dashboard_v6.1.0.55920.2_.aspx?mode=js

Did we miss something?

3 - Also the tridion MTSUser, should it be a local Administrators on server? Can we change this user post installation (like for running Tridion com+ services)?

4-  Since we have migrated, we have all the existing tridion administrators present in database. With which user should we log in, when we access tridion for first time? will any existing tridion Administrator do?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the user that you are logging in as still a valid administrator? Did you, for example, change domains?

Comment: The Tridion MTS user (do we still call it that?) needs to be a Tridion adminsistrator, but not necessarily a Windows adminstrator. Ask Customer Support for their security white-paper which should give you some insights into this kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks Dominic, perhaps we will raise this with Customer support.

Comment: Please mark one answer as "accepted" by clicking the large check mark to the left of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks for your  valuable inputs.
This error was because the default tridion user (MTSuser) did not have access to Database.
Even after giving access, we had to reinstall tridion to resolve the issue.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

That's a lot of questions Huston. I'll answer where I can.

1+3 - Given that you do see the Publications, but not the System administration items, I'd check what account is specified in the Tridion COM+ application.

2 - For your second problem, check the actual content of that URL. Typically it contains an error 500 response that your browser is now trying to parse as JavaScript.

4 - Since your users already existed before the migration, you should be able to log on with any of them.

It looks like your problems might all be caused by the same cause: which is hiding behind #2 or #3.

Comment: More error details after double clicking the 404 error in ribbon:

Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)